# PostgreSQL backup and restore

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm having trouble restoring a PostgreSQL backup.

On my own computer I dump a table using the custom backup format.

On the server, I try to restore the file but it gives me several errors:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 247; 1259 147321 TABLE county postgres
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  type "geometry" does not exist
```

This is what I've done on the server:

```
pSql -U postgres
/c justice
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;

pg_restore -p 5432 -U postgres -d justice data_import
```

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.3.2 on both computers.  However I've got PostGIS 2.1.1 on my local computer and 2.0.4 on the server. Could that be a problem?

Why is my PostGIS extension not working on the server?

When I do not specify the database it seems to work.  However where does the data go?  It also writes out all the SQL statements to the screen.

```
pg_restore -p 5432 -U postgres public_county
PostgreSQL database dump complete
```

When I try to verify the installation of PostGIS it gives me an error.  I think the extension might be improperly installed:

```
select PostGIS_full_version();
ERROR:  function postgis_full_version() does not exist
```

Comment: If you don't specify  the database, `pg_restore` extracts the dump to SQL format and prints it to stdout. So it's not really "going" anywhere. It's a way to convert custom-format dumps to SQL-format dumps.

Comment: Great. That solves part of my problem.  Now I've got to figure out why it isn't recognizing my postgis extension.

Comment: Could I have created a postgis extension that doesn't include any functions?

Comment: This looks like a "created extension in wrong database" or "wrong search_path" problem to me.

Comment: This is my search path:  "$user",public    And the user is probably 'postgres'.

Comment: I think you have indeed made an extension without any functions.  I believe that usually you have to run 2 files against the database to make it spatially-enabled in PostGIS, and they're usually called postgis.sql and spatial_ref_sys.sql in your PostGIS directory.

Comment: That sounds correct.  I've been trying to get my webhost support to do this. They have correctly installed postgresql, but after a lot of back and forth messages - they finally gave up on trying to install postgis.  There might be a conflict with Cpanel?  Or the Centos install package?